# How can I reset my Javascript program?

Tags: javascript, html, reload

I am trying to make a sort of a physics program in javascript but when its over i want to reload it. I want to do this without reloading the page (if this is possible..). It`s the plan to get a javascript code in the button to reload it.

here is my try on the site: `tap.96.lt`

I hope I am clear enough, thank for helping!

code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style>
#my_canvas {
max-width: 98%;
max-height: 98%;
height: auto;
width: auto;
margin:auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color:white;
border: black 3px solid;
}
#center {
max-width: 66.5%;
max-height: 95%;
height: auto;
width: auto;
margin:auto;
background:;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
Body {
background-color: slategrey;
}    
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

function Canvas(){
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var snelheid = 20;
var balpic = new Image();
var grondpic = new Image();
balpic.src = "bal.png";
grondpic.src = "grond.png";

function reset() {

}

function blok(){
    this.h = 100, this.w = 100, this.x = (ctx.canvas.width*0.5)-(this.w*0.5), this.y =     (ctx.canvas.height*0.2)-(this.h*0.5), this.color = "Blue", this.dir = "down", this.valsnel     = 0, this.tijd = 0, this.afstand = 0, this.src = balpic;
    this.draw = function() {

        //plaats berekenen
            // kijken of blok de grond raakt
            if(grond.y-9<=this.y+this.h){this.dir = "up";};
            // kijken of blok niet uit scherm is
            if(this.y<=0){this.dir = "down";};
            // valsnelheid mag niet negatief zijn
            if(this.valsnel<=0){this.dir="down"}
            // blok mag niet ver onder de grond komen
            if(grond.y+15<=this.y+this.h){this.dir = "stil";};

        //valsnelheid berekenen
            // tijd berekenen
            if(this.dir=="down"){this.tijd = this.tijd+0.2;};
            if(this.dir=="up"){this.tijd = this.tijd-0.5};
            if(this.dir=="stil"){this.tijd = 0};

        this.valsnel = (9.81*this.tijd)+0.0000000001

        if(this.dir=="up"){this.y=this.y-this.valsnel};
        if(this.dir=="down"){this.y=this.y+this.valsnel};
        if(this.dir=="stil"){this.y=this.y}

        //tekenen
        //ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        //ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);

        ctx.drawImage(this.src,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);

        //alert("y is "+ this.y +" en tijd is "+ this.tijd +" en valsnelheid is "+     this.valsnel +" en de afstand is "+ this.afstand)
    }
}

function grond(){
    this.w = ctx.canvas.width, this.x = 0, this.y = ctx.canvas.height*0.8, this.h =     ctx.canvas.height*0.2, this.color = "black", this.src = grondpic;
    this.draw = function() {
        //tekenen
        //ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        //ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);

        ctx.drawImage(this.src,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
    }
}

// alle functies
var blok = new blok();
var grond = new grond();

function draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);


    //draw
    grond.draw();
    blok.draw();
    //draw


    ctx.restore();
}

var animateInterval = setInterval(draw,snelheid);


document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight
    var mouseX = event.clientX - ((x-ctx.canvas.width)*0.5)
    var mouseY = event.clientY - ((y-ctx.canvas.height)*0.5)
    var status = document.getElementById('status');


    status.innerHTML = mouseX+" | "+mouseY+" screen width "+x+"  "+y;
});
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
Canvas();
});
    </script>
    <h2 id="status"></h2>
    <input id="clickme" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="canvas()" />
    <div id="center">
    <canvas id="my_canvas" width="700" height="1000">
        Please get a new browser to watch canvas!
    </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, not clear enough. There's really no reason to "reset" JavaScript. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It would be helpful to post more of your code so that the great users here can help give suggestions.

Comment: I want to reset the javascript to replay my canvas

Comment: Can't you invoke call Canvas() again?

Comment: Thats the site: tap.96.lt

Comment: Do it by setting your variables/states/objects to their default values, in other-words the value they had when the page loaded.

Comment: @Thomas - we're not going to your site and debugging your entire site; include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: cant it go more easily?

Comment: sorry i wil post the code

Comment: @Pointy Actually it does make sense. I "reset" all the time when I'm doing HTML5 game development. For example when a player dies and they ran out of life's you can *reset* the game, but you don't want to reload the entire page and have the user wait.

Comment: I am new in programming and only 12 years and I don`t understand why my question is being devoted.. I am trying to do get the best out of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clear the interval that draws on the canvas.
2. Re-initiate the drawings.

   For these 2 steps fill your reset function with these lines.

   ```
   function reset() {
       clearInterval(animateInterval);
       Canvas();
   }
   ```
3. Instead defining the onclick event inside the button html, define the onclick event inside the Canvas() function. Otherwise you cannot call the reset() method inside canvas function.

   For this step, after the reset function add this line.

   ```
   document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = reset;
   ```

   Then remove onclick event definition from button html

   ```
   <input id="clickme" type="button" value="clickme">
   ```